# How to call a function from button inside echo in php?

Tags: php

I am trying to pass a variable from one php function to another.
1st function creates a button.
2nd function needs to be able to receive variable that button sent to the 2nd function.

Nothing happens when i click the button. Page just flickers.

```
<?php
    function myFunc(){
        $filename = "123";
        echo '<form method="post"><input type="submit" name="button1"class="button" value="Button1" onclick="myOtherFunc("tomato")" /></form>';
 }

 myFunc();

 function myOtherFunc($filename){
    echo '$filename'."anyting ?" ;
 }
```

Comment: JavaScript and PHP are different Languages. PHP executes on the Server before anything is sent to the Browser. Your `func_ImageView` is in PHP for no reason that makes sense to me. Just put it in JavaScript, or echo the function as a String *(which I don't recommend)*.

Comment: Right now i am not concerned about javascript.
I cant run php function inside php.
Whats inside the function is not the question right now. Right now function is not called and i dont understand why

Comment: A function defined in PHP is not seen by the Client in the HTML or JavaScript.

Comment: Because when you echo the input, it is considered a rendered HTML (client-side). The PHP function will do its part when the browser is loading. In your case, you should use the javascript function when the button is clicked, not PHP. And if you want to communicate between client-server, you should use ajax or something equivalent

Answer (score 2):

Onclick will not execute php code. PHP code is executed on the server BEFORE your page is rendered. Once your page is rendered, the only code that can be executed without reloading the page is Javascript. The onclick attribute on your button will look for a Javascript function called func_ImageView, which does not exist. If you want the content if your func_ImageView function to be called, you need to call that code in php, but you should instead use javascript for this from what it looks like.

Comment: Please leave javascript alone for now.
I updated the code so make it less confusing

Comment: @TonyNameless You are still trying to call a php function from within the DOM. This is not possible.

Comment: If you want the content if your func_ImageView function to be called, you need to call that code in php, but you should instead use javascript for this from what it looks like ?

OK i like where this is going.
Question now is: Example ?